# OpenXML removing #REF from xml file in excel C#

Tags: c#, xml, excel, winforms

Issue:. Corrupt named ranges can to accumulate in the workbook XML and slow the workbook down, and cause error messages when worksheets are copied between workbooks. A workbook can only contain one range with a given name, so if two worksheets containing identical range names come together, it will produce an error.

Once way named ranges can become useless/corrupted is en the cells to which they refer are deleted They can be identified from the #REF error which appears:

[image]

My goal is to remove any #REF in the xml file within my excel file. I plan on using `DocumentFormats.OpenXML`. Currently I'm making a copy of my old excel file I then want to be able to access the XML within the new copy of the excel file.

```
                System.IO.File.Copy(txbBrowse.Text, Path.Combine(Path.GetDirectoryName(txbBrowse.Text), Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(txbBrowse.Text) + "Repair" + DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd-HH-mm-ss") + Path.GetExtension(txbBrowse.Text)));
```

I'm currently using WinFroms in C#

I can't seem to find any links on how I would achieve my goal. Any ideas on how I would go about opening and editing my XML file to remove all the #REF in my new copy of the excel file? If someone could give me some advice on this matter or refer me to a few links I would appreciate it.

Comment: Why are you getting so many errors in the first place? Fix the root of the problem.

Comment: It's not my own problem. It's other peoples problem I'm trying to fix